# Cherry-pick-ing and smart diff-ing

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Situation: A local repository has branch `A` and branch `B`. Branch `B` is ahead of branch `A` by, let's say, 30 commits.

First question:
Can I list all the commits that are in `B` that are not in `A` ?

Second question: Let's say I cherry pick some (completely random) commits from `B` into `A`. What will happen if after that I try to merge `B` into `A`? Will I get duplicated commits? Can this be avoided somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the first question,

```
git log --left-right --graph --cherry-pick --oneline B...A
```

to get a list of different commits between the branches.

After merging one branch with the other git will automatically keep only one copy of duplicate commits. In any case if any conflict, git will ask you to resolve it manually.

Comment: What is the difference between ```B..A``` and ```B...A``` ?

Comment: Oh, so basically 3 points will return the "remaining" difference after I do a cherry pick, right?

Comment: Three dots will return all commits from both branches except those in common. With two dots you will get only the commits in A that are not in B.

Comment: Didn't the OP need `B..A`, that is, `B ^A` instead?  `B...A` is the symmetric difference -- see "SPECIFYING RANGES" in the [`gitrevisions(7)`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) manual page.